# "a soul that dies" or "a dead soul"?

Tags: grammaticality

Are these two phrases both the same meaning? I would say "a **dead** soul" or "a soul that **has died**", how can I understand "a soul that **dies**"?

More context here: this was found in a song lyrics.

> I wonder is there hope for us
>   A place where we can all be free
>   I wonder is there life inside **a soul that dies**?
>   I wonder is there hope for us
>   To lift me up I don't know when
>   I'll see the sun again
>   I'd like to feel alive
>   Just one more time

Comment: Would you have additional context for your examples?

Comment: @Peter more context added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, there is a big difference between using

> **a soul that dies**

and

> **a dead soul**
>   a soul that **has died**

since the lyrics of your song is contrasting how a soul is *before* and *after* death, whereas the last two examples already assume the soul is dead.  The first phrase does not make this assumption, but leaves open the possibility that *death may occur*.

EDIT:

In Western Christian thought, a **soul** is what is left of a person after they die, being synonymous to ***spirit***.   The **soul** itself does not *physically* die as the body does.  However, one's *moral compass* is also referred to as one's **soul**. So, in a metaphoric sense if one's **soul dies**, one has lost their *moral bearings*, usually this is referred to as

> **losing one's soul**

So, depending on what you mean you could say

> I wonder, is there life **inside** a soul when it dies.

but better might be

> I wonder, is there life **in** a soul when it dies.

You would also need to supply context for what you mean by "***life***".

Comment: So, can I consider this sentence as "I wonder, is there life inside a soul when it dies"?

Comment: nitpick: "In Western Christian thought, a soul is what is left of a person after they die, being synonymous to spirit." Not quite accurate at all. The soul is what animates the body. Death is the separation of soul from body.

Comment: You have given me a detailed answer to what a soul is all about. However, what I really want to know is what the word "die" means when used in present tense. Whether it has any difference in meaning from its past tense/perfect tense form.

Comment: "His soul **dies** every time his team *loses*.", "His soul **died** every time his team *lost*." both have the same meaning, the first also projects into the future, the second only talks about the past, but in the context people will understand if his team loses again, his soul will die again. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Note that song lyrics, like poetry, often make grammatical choices that are less about strict word meaning than about having the correct number of syllables or patterns of stress (the latter is formally called **metric structure** or just **metre**).

In the song lyric you've posted, every line (except possibly the last one) is made up of [iambs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iamb_(poetry)); that is, alternating weak and strong syllables that give you a "da-DUM-da-DUM-da-DUM" pattern.  Presumably this matches the strong and weak beats in the music.

If we look at the line that you're asking about, and I bold the stressed syllables, you get this:

> I **won**-der **is** there **life** in-**side** a **soul** that **dies**?

That's perfect "iambic hexameter" (six sets of weak-strong pairs).

If we try out the changes you suggest:

> 1. I **won**-der **is** there **life** in-**side** a **dead** **soul**?

That's five iambs with one extra stressed syllable tacked on the end.

> 2. I **won**-der **is** there **life** in-**side** a **soul** that has **died**?

That's five iambs, then an extra unstressed syllable, and then another iamb.

With songs, as opposed to poetry, you can fake the metre a bit by adding in extra syllables between the beats of the music or dropping them out, so the beats of the song stay constant while the pattern of the words gets a bit more irregular.  But songwriters who consider themselves poets often to try to stick to a regular metre when possible, even when that means making unusual vocabulary or grammatical choices.

Comment: Really helpful information, I didn't even think of that. Thank you! However, my main problem is to use "die" correctly in its present simple tense. In my experience, "die" is always in its continuous/perfect/past simple tense form. It looks strange to me when it is used in present simple tense.

Comment: @preachers - Present simple is also used for habitual or generally-applicable statements.  For example, "Everyone tries to postpone death, but in the end, everyone dies."  You could understand this phrase "a soul that dies" as being equivalent to "any soul that might die."  That is, it's a question about souls in general, not about one particular soul.